# Why does removing a class is not working?

Tags: javascript

I have a script that should allow me to add/remove a class to a `div`. It works to the extend that it adds the `highlight` class but after that, it does not remove it. Is anyone aware what should be changed in order to create the desired effect of adding and removing the `highlight` class.
I would appreciate some opinion, thanks :)

```js
<script>

    let highlightsEnabled = false
    function toggleVizualization() {
      if (highlightsEnabled) {
        highlightsEnabled = false
      } else {
        highlightsEnabled = true
      }
      document.querySelector('#highlights-msg').innerText = (
        highlightsEnabled ? '' :
                            ''
      )
      ;[].slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('grid div')).forEach(div => {
        if (highlightsEnabled) {
          div.classList.add('highlight')
        } else {
          div.classList.remove('higlight')
        }
      })
    }
    document.addEventListener('keypress', ev => {
      if (!ev.metaKey && !ev.ctrlKey && !ev.altKey) {
        if (ev.key == "s" || ev.key == "S") {
          ev.preventDefault()
          ev.stopPropagation()
          toggleVizualization()
        }
      }
    }, {passive:false, capture:true})

    </script>
```

Comment: do you have a `grid` tag ? or should that selector be `.grid div` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a typo in

```
div.classList.remove('higlight')
```

`higlight` should be `highlight` (notice the missing h)

Comment: There's a close reason for typos.

Comment: Thanks @Taplar I wasn't aware of that. Learned something new today!

Answer (score 0):

I think you misspelled "highlight." It needs another "h" in the middle.

```
div.classList.remove('higlight')
```

Comment: There's a close reason for typos.

Comment: I don't think I have that privilege yet.

Comment: @user1599011 You don't have the privilege to vote to close a question, but you do have to privilege to flag a question for closure for that reason. Either way, answering these kinds of questions is discouraged. It is very unlikely to help anyone so it just adds noise when people search for an answer to their problem. Answering it makes it harder for [the automated system](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) to delete these questions. (It still might be manually deleted by users who have that privilege, but that does cost more effort.)